# Changing the value of a boolean variable as a result of an *ngIf

Tags: html, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I made an app where a user has to enter his address details which then stores it in firebase what I am trying to do is make it so if a user already stored his address it will not display the address entry form again but instead will show address information but I am not sure how to go about it.

I have tried using (ionChange) to call a function and change a boolean variables value to show either the users address details if they exist and the form if they do not it has not worked.

Here is the code for what I have tried

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let a of Addresses|async'>
    <ng-container *ngIf='a.UID == firebase.id;else other_content'>
      <ion-card (ionChange)='addressExists()'>
        {{a.City}}
      </ion-card>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #other_content>
      <ng-container  (ionChange)='addressDoesNotExist()'></ng-container>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
```

TS

```
 Addresses;
  Exists = false;
  constructor(public afAuth:AngularFireAuth, public firebase: FirebaseProvider, 
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public auth: AuthProvider) {
    this.Addresses = this.firebase.getAddresses();

}

addressExists(){
  this.Exists = true;
}

addressDoesNotExist(){
  this.Exists = false;
}
```

here is what my data looks like on firebase: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzTN3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a need to store a boolean value. You can do:

HTML:`<ng-container *ngIf='addressExists(a);else other_content'>`

TS: `addressExists(address) { return address.uid === this.firebase.id }`

Now if addressExists returns true it will display:

```
<ion-card>
  {{a.City}}
</ion-card>
```

else it will display:

```
<ng-template #other_content>
  <ng-container>... your form ...</ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works, I didn't know about this method feels like it could have helped me solved multiple of my problems.

Comment: If possible can you help me into another problem I ran into? because I use ngFor to compare the address id to current logged in ID it will keep comparing so even after it finds the user and shows his address it then displays the form because the next ID does not match: https://imgur.com/a/9E9iLaG

Comment: As far as I understand now you have an address list with all addresses for all users. Then there is no need to do a ngFor. Just create a method that checks if the address exists in the list. Call that in you constructor or ngOnInit. If so, store it in your component. Then display either address or form based on if the address exists in component.

Comment: In other words, why have all addresses retrieved in this component if you only need one? Instead of calling getAddresses(), create a new method getAddress() on the FirebaseProvider.

Comment: I am new to firebase so I was just following the steps I usually get taught in class. Can you give me a bit of code to work with on how to do this?

Comment: If you could provide the code you have in Stackblitz or any other online editor, then I can look into your project. Now I just don't have enough information to help you. It is also a different question you are asking now.

Comment: I am having trouble with the drag and drop feature for on stackblitz and I never used an online editor so I am having trouble with it. I followed your advice and removed the ngFor and i tried subscribing to firebase and looping through all the objects and if the id's are equal it stores it in a variable, then I made a condition if the object is greater than 0 (not empty) It should not display the form.

Comment: this.firebase.getAddresses().subscribe(
      response=>{
        for(let i in response)
        { 
         if(this.firebase.id == response[i].UID)
          {
            this.Addresses = response[i];
          }
        }
      })

Comment: <ng-container *ngIf='Addresses?.length > 0;else other_content'>
      <ion-card id='card'>
      <div align = 'center'> <ion-icon name='home'><ion-card-title>Your Address</ion-card-title></ion-icon></div>
        {{Addresses.City}}
        {{Addresses.hNo}}
        {{Addresses.rNo}}
        {{Addresses.Blk}}
      </ion-card>
  </ng-container>

Comment: Sorry about the ugly format but this is the only way I know how to show code.

Comment: Never mind I think it works when i tried specifying a variable of the object like Addresses?.City?.length > 0 the form disappeared. You have been a great help. Thank you very much